# getting a json result in android

Tags: android, json

I'm trying to do a basic request from my Galaxy SII to the DB on my computer which has a wamp setup.

The app crashes and closes on the phone. I think it's doing it at the httpPost as nothing is showing up in the access log of the apache server. (The web service works fine through my phone's browser). I'm getting NullPointerExeptions in the logCat in Eclipse.

After looking up info for a while I have no idea what I'm supposed to be doing to get a json result through an Android app. I thought the code below is really all you need, give or take a couple of minor alterations.

Is there anything I can change to my code or should I discard it and try a different approach?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String result = null;
    InputStream is = null;
    StringBuilder sb=null;

    ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

  //http post
    try{
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.1.1.11/food/food.php");
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        is = entity.getContent();
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
    }

    //convert response to string
    try{
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
        String line="0";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }

        is.close();
        result=sb.toString();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }

  //paring data
    int fd_id = 0;
    String fd_name = null;
    JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
    try{
    jArray = new JSONArray(result);
    JSONObject json_data=null;

    for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
            json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
            fd_id=json_data.getInt("FOOD_ID");
            fd_name=json_data.getString("FOOD_NAME");
    }

    }catch(JSONException e1){
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Food Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }catch (ParseException e1){
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), fd_name, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: what exactly does your logcat say? which line it is showing the exception at?

Answer (score 0):

You should never make network calls from the application thread. You need to put your network call in a Service, Thread, or an AsyncTask.

Comment: Hi David. Can you direct to any info on how to do my HttpPost as an Async Task?

Answer (score 0):

You should do your network communications in an asynctask like this:

```
class talkToServer extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String>{


@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
//http post
try{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.1.1.11/food/food.php");
    httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    is = entity.getContent();
}catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
}

//convert response to string
try{
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
    sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append(reader.readLine() + "\n");
    String line="0";

    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        sb.append(line + "\n");
    }

    is.close();
    result=sb.toString();

}catch(Exception e){
    Log.e("log_tag", "Error converting result "+e.toString());
}

//paring data
int fd_id = 0;
String fd_name = null;
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray();
try{
jArray = new JSONArray(result);
JSONObject json_data=null;

for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
        json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
        fd_id=json_data.getInt("FOOD_ID");
        fd_name=json_data.getString("FOOD_NAME");
}

}catch(JSONException e1){
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No Food Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}catch (ParseException e1){
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

return fd_name;

}

@Override
public void onPostExecute(String temp){

Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), temp, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
}
```